# Jersey - regular expression in @path

Tags: regex, jersey

I am using the following annotation for one of the resources:

```
@Path ("/{path: [a-zA-Z0-9_/.]+}/rename")
```

It works well except that i don't receive any special characters, such as space (%20).
What should i add to the regular expression to allow all unicode characters as well?

Comment: I've never really used Jersey - would it be being passed as an actual unicode character, or a % code?  Also, what are you trying to edit out that causes you to need your own Regular Expression?  Why not `/{path}/rename`?  Are you trying to capture forward slashes?  Could you use `/{path: .+}/rename`?  I'm afraid we'll need to know a bit more about your use case.

Comment: Hey - I'd really like to help you with this problem...